# Create grid from raster with equal size squares

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, wgs84, vector-grid

I have a raster of the globe with coordinate system WGS_84.

I want to create a grid on that raster where every square has the same size.

When I use the Create Fishnet tool the size of squares get bigger as I move away from the equator.

Is there a way to make a grid where every square has the same size or at least where the differences between squares are small?

Comment: You need to change your definition of "same size", since the tool is producing shapes with **equal area** (the area of one square degree shrinks as you get closer to the poles, so the tool is either compensating, or being populated in a projected coordinate system (with correct Cartesian area)).

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking you might have not specificied the exact number of rows and columns and that it created the fishnet best on the area of coverage. ArcGIS resources provide ["How Create Fishnet works"](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000030000000) which gives a good overview of the tool and the parameters to work with.

> Creating a fishnet requires three basic pieces of information: the spatial extent of the fishnet, the number of rows and columns, and the angle of rotation. There are a variety of ways to specify this basic information. **For example, you might not know the exact number of rows and columns, but you do know that each rectangular cell must be exactly 110 meters by 63 meters and must cover the spatial extent of another feature class.**

The tool has 11 parameters, and you should think of these in four distinct groups:

```
The spatial extent of fishnet
The number of rows and columns and height and width of each cell in the fishnet
The angle of rotation for the fishnet  
Parameters that define the output feature class name and type
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.
It's true that I don't specify the number of rows and columns but from what I understand giving the exact size of each cell should be enough.